# Separate file for storing large python lists

Tags: python

I have a big list in my main python script containing hundreds of rows. I will refer to it as `myBigList`

Example sample code for this list:

```
myBigList = ['listentry0',
 'listentry1',
 'listentry2',
 'listentry3',
 'listentry4',
 'listentry5',
 'listentry6',
 'listentry7',
 'listentry8',
 'listentry9']
```

How can I import this list from another file? Should I create a second `myBigLists.py` file in the same directory and import it to the main script?

Comment: What do you mean by "storing"? Can't you serialize your list to say, a JSON file and re-open it when you need it?

Comment: Better store that list in a proper serialized format like csv. You can read it from any script that requires it.

Comment: If this list are input data, then use serialization to file. But if it is data needed for working script (rare change) then parsing data on every script start is stupid and time consuming. Then it should be stored in separated python file or in binary file. (binary file reading is faster)

Comment: @Grzegorz Bokota   How would you store it in a separated python file?

Comment: As variable. Then import to main file/

Answer (score 0):

You could write this list line by line in a text file:

```
#myBigList = [str("listentry" + str(i)) for i in range(500)]
MyBigList = ["listentry {}".format(i) for i in range(500)]

with open("Output_file.txt", "w") as output_file:
    for line in MyBigList:
        output_file.write(line + "\n")
```